# R tidyr gather() two sets of columns based on lookup

Tags: r, tidyr, data-manipulation

I've got a dataset of results from a satisfaction survey by region. Each question in the survey is rated on a 4-point scale (from *Very Satisfied* to *Very Dissatisfied*). Each row in the dataset contains the aggregated result for a given question in a given region at the end of a given 'fiscal year'. It also contains the total number of respondents for each level.

This is what the dataset looks like

```
testdf=data.frame(FY=c("FY13","FY14","FY15","FY14","FY15","FY13","FY14","FY15","FY13","FY15","FY13","FY14","FY15","FY13","FY14","FY15"),
                  Region=c(rep("AFRICA",5),rep("ASIA",5),rep("AMERICA",6)),
                  QST=c(rep("Q2",3),rep("Q5",2),rep("Q2",3),rep("Q5",2),rep("Q2",3),rep("Q5",3)),
                  Very.Satisfied=runif(16,min = 0, max=1),
                  Total.Very.Satisfied=floor(runif(16,min=10,max=120)),
                  Satisfied=runif(16,min = 0, max=1),
                  Total.Satisfied=floor(runif(16,min=10,max=120)),
                  Dissatisfied=runif(16,min = 0, max=1),
                  Total.Dissatisfied=floor(runif(16,min=10,max=120)),
                  Very.Dissatisfied=runif(16,min = 0, max=1),
                  Total.Very.Dissatisfied=floor(runif(16,min=10,max=120))
                  )
```

**My Objective**

My objective is to reshape the dataset from a wide to a long format, by first creating a column called `Level` (which indicates the level from the 4 point scale). Then creating a column called `Score` with the aggregated scores and last column called `Total` with the total number of respondents for each corresponding level.

**My Attempt**

So far, I have just been able to `gather` ***the levels*** into a single column, and create the `Score` column.

```
#Gather Satisfation levels
library(tidyverse)
testfinal = testdf %>% gather(Level,Score,-FY:-QST,-Total.Very.Satisfied,-Total.Satisfied,-Total.Dissatisfied,-Total.Very.Dissatisfied) %>%
  select(1:3,8:9,4:7)
```

I am unable to figure out how to `gather` ***the totals*** into another column *such that each total in the newly created* `Total` *column corresponds to the level associated with it.*

Here a preview of what the final dataset would look like, if all goes well

```
#FY   #Region  #QST  #Level            #Score        #Total
 FY13  AFRICA   Q2    Very.Satisfied    0.73080770    48
 FY14  AFRICA   Q2    Very.Satisfied    0.58686424    97
 FY15  AFRICA   Q2    Very.Satisfied    0.07358698    34
 FY14  AFRICA   Q5    Very.Satisfied    0.59996830    22
```

*and so on...*

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done more easily with `melt` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), `melt` from 'wide' to 'long' while specifying the multiple column name `patterns` in the `measure` argument

```
library(data.table)
out <- melt(setDT(testdf), measure = patterns("^Total", 
     "^(Very|Satisfied|Dis)"), value.name = c("Total", "Score"), 
       variable.name = "Level")
nm1 <- names(testdf)[c(4, 6, 8, 10)]
out[, Level := nm1[Level]][]
head(out)
#     FY Region QST          Level Total      Score
#1: FY13 AFRICA  Q2 Very.Satisfied    85 0.36888202
#2: FY14 AFRICA  Q2 Very.Satisfied   108 0.67589979
#3: FY15 AFRICA  Q2 Very.Satisfied    13 0.90792351
#4: FY14 AFRICA  Q5 Very.Satisfied    52 0.01966743
#5: FY15 AFRICA  Q5 Very.Satisfied    59 0.68895083
#6: FY13   ASIA  Q2 Very.Satisfied    96 0.24912066
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
testdf %>%
    gather(key, val, 4:ncol(.)) %>%
    extract(key, into = c("key1", "Level"), "(Total)?\\.?(.*)") %>%
    mutate(key1 = replace_na(key1, "Score")) %>%
    spread(key1, val)
#      FY  Region QST             Level      Score Total
#1  FY13  AFRICA  Q2      Dissatisfied 0.69226483    71
#2  FY13  AFRICA  Q2         Satisfied 0.91617425    26
#3  FY13  AFRICA  Q2 Very.Dissatisfied 0.64277110    43
#4  FY13  AFRICA  Q2    Very.Satisfied 0.36888202    85
#5  FY13 AMERICA  Q2      Dissatisfied 0.10219036    37
#6  FY13 AMERICA  Q2         Satisfied 0.28281065    26
#7  FY13 AMERICA  Q2 Very.Dissatisfied 0.59667659    90
#8  FY13 AMERICA  Q2    Very.Satisfied 0.30204224    76
# ....
```

NOTE: The values in 'Total', 'Score' are different as there was no `set.seed` while creating the dataset.